# How to mock patch ctypes.WinDLL in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to write unit test which checks function parameters:

```
def test_my_function():
    my_function = mock.patch('mymodule.myclass.myfuction')
```

My fuction looks like this in mymodule:

```
from ctypes import POINTER, WinDLL, c_int, cast, pointer, byref

class myclass:
    def myfunction():
        # some logic
```

Test fails with error message:

`ImportError: cannot import name WinDLL`

So, I'm trying to mock patch `ctypes.WinDLL` in my test:

```
mocker.patch('ctypes.WinDLL')
my_function = mock.patch('mymodule.myclass.myfuction')
```

Got error:

`AttributeError: <module 'ctypes' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.pyc'> does not have the attribute 'WinDLL`

I cannot mock patch WinDll, because `ctypes` defines `WinDLL` if  client uses Windows. My os is Linux.

Is it possible to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I've found solution myself. By default `mocker.patch` patches only defined attributes. It's possible to mock non existing attribute, passing argument `create=True`:

`mocker.patch('ctypes.WinDLL', create=True)`